# help with webservice call

Tags: webservices

The following is the Webservice class I wrote. But I have a doubt does this serve my purpose because of the following reasons.
I edited this code as per the comments and it is working .

```
global class VFRequestAndResponse{
   public static List<results> res;
     webservice static String requestAndResponse(string realId, blob blobMsg,Integer code, string statMsg){
         string responseVar;
         Integer respCode;
         string msg;
         res=new List<results>();
         if(realId != '' && blodMsg != '' &&  code ==0 && statMsg != ''){
            respCode= 1; // indicates the request is success
            msg = 'xyz';
            res.add(new results(respCode, msg );
         }
        return res;
    }

   public class results{
     String msg;
     Integer respCode;

    public results(Integer c, String v){
        msg = v;
        respCode = c;
    }
  }
}
```

I share this Webservice class wsdl with third party.
They make a request with the 4 parameters as shown in the class.

1) Among these 4 parameters I have response in 2 parameters which I need to read and show on the vf page.

2)When they make a request I should update and send the other two parameters as response.
Please suggest me does this possible.
Brief explanation why I wrote the above weservice.
When I make a request I receive acknowledge, since the actual response need time  to come and when they find my requested result they call the websevice I shared.

From here my webservice come into action
Therefore  the thirdparty send the reponse in the request it self and expect the respond back to their request.
In the later time I should capture the response I recived in a request need to be shown on vfpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing web services / rest method you should return the response in some for of structured object (if it includes multiple parameters) You can do this using Inner class and JSON...Observe:

```
global class VFRequestAndResponse{

    webservice static String requestAndResponse(string realId, String blodMsg,Integer code, string statMsg){
         String responseVar;
         Integer respCode;
         string msg;

        if(realId != '' && blodMsg != '' &&  code ==0 && statMsg != ''){
            respCode= 1; // indicates the request is success
            msg = 'xyz';
            responseVar = JSON.Serialize(New Results(msg,respCode));
        }
        return responseVar;
    }


    public class results{
        String msg;
        Integer respCode;

        public results(String v, Integer c){
            msg = v;
            respCode = c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error.  Error Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from String to VFRequestAndResponse.results at line 11 column 13

Comment: Try now..............

Comment: I think it would be better to return the `results` object itself and let the framework represent the two values in the XSD in the WSDL (rather than users having to also know what the JSON structure is).

Comment: @keith good point. Easy to change to do that

Comment: @Eric I tried to make the changes as Keith said but I a getting the following error could you please correct me what I am doing wrong. I udated my question to reflect my changes.   Error: Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [VFRequestAndResponse.results].<Constructor>() at line 9 column 20

Comment: @suri - You have your parameters switched, the signature is String, integer so you need `res.add(new results(msg, respCode );`